# how to use regex in MultiItemReader spring batch

Tags: java, spring

Hello there Java wizards,

I am having trouble with the MultiItemReader.

I need to read csv file but I need to be case insensitive even for the extention. so the question is : is it possible to uses regex in MultiItemReader.

Rigth after a sample of my code :

```
<bean id="kiosqueFiletemMultiReader" class=" org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader" scope="step">
    <property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters['inputFolder']}/**/*.csv" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReaderKiosque" />
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance for your answers :)